# split and combine multiple cookies in request using spring interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cookies

My application is making use of cookie .e.g `App_Cookie`.  But now I have seen that due to increase in length of fields stored in cookie, cookie size is going beyond 4 kb limit and browser is rejecting the cookie. Application is built using Java, Spring Boot.

I was thinking of splitting the cookie content into two cookies e.g. `App_Cookie1` and `App_Cookie2`

The idea is to

- split the cookies into two after execution returns from Controller.

If the length of added `AppCookie` is more than 4kb. e.g 5k. Split it to two - `AppCookie1` (3k) and `AppCookie2` (2k), so that browser receives 2 smaller cookies.

- combine the contents of `AppCookie1` (3k) and `AppCookie2` (2k) to single cookie `AppCookie`. So that when execution reaches controller layer, it can use the `AppCookie` itself.

`App_Cookie` is being read at multiple places in application, to avoid the code change at multiple places, I am thinking to make use of request/response interceptor.

**My questions are:**

- Can this be done using interceptor and is it recommended way?
- Can we modify request/response headers in `preHandle()`. Could not find a way to add/remove cookies in request.
- Any other alternative which can simplify this case. Wanted to avoid split/combine logic change at multiple places.

```java
public class CustomHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(CustomHandlerInterceptor.class);
    
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("********** Before Handler execution"); 
        Cookie app_cookie1 = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "App_Cookie1");
        Cookie app_cookie2 = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "App_Cookie2");
        // combine logic so that controllers can use App_Cookie
        // Combine contents of App_Cookie1 and App_Cookie2 and create new App_Cookie with that
        // remove App_Cookie1 and App_Cookie2 from request
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object, ModelAndView model)
            throws Exception {
        LOG.info("*********** After Handler execution"); 
        // split logic after controller adds AppCookie
        // read App_Cookie and split to two Cookies App_Cookie1 and App_Cookie2 and add to response
        // remove App_Cookie from response
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if you need an `App_Cookie3` or `App_Cookie4` or ... You cannot remove cookies from the request nor add a new one, that can only be done at the response. This will also fail if the response has already been written, you cannot change anything than. I would say you have to see why you are writing so much to the cookie in the first place, as such large cookies are generally a sign of a bad design (imho).

Comment: @M.Deinum yes there is a plan to get rid of this design in future, this is more of temporary fix for the time being so that application works fine. So if we cannot modify request object in prehandle, I think I have to add the combine logic at all places where application tried to read cookie. I was looking for this to be abstracted out at single place.